# How to configure phpmyadmin for Lan in Xamp?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using Xampp.I am trying to access from another system in the LAN. And My Ip address 192.168.1.2.And When I am trying to connect

```
http://192.168.1.2/phpmyadmin
```

I got the phpmyadmin page.But when I am trying to connect using

```
mysql_connect('192.168.1.2','root','')
```

It throws an error

```
could not connect to database(10060)
```

I dont know why?Please helpme on this.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is still running on the same server as mySQL. The `192.168.1.2` part is only for clients to connect to the server.

Use the local address to connect:

```
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','')
```

Comment: but I want to connect to that database from outside  machine.(i.e.From LAN)That doesnt conatain the phpmyadmin

Comment: @vinoth then you probably have a firewall problem. Better suited on serverfault.com

Comment: May be.But I configured some of the things for this.So I think there may be I need to configure some more things.